# How to resolve asynchronous function it's not returning data in time when fastify sends the request

Tags: javascript, database, fastify

Items in the first log does work
while in the second log gives just empty array
I guess it's because it's not loaded yet, how to fix

I was trying async and await but nothing works

```js
const db = require("playerio-node");

const index = async(fastify, options, done) => {

    fastify.get("/pricing", async(req, res) => {
        let items = [];
        db.PlayerIO.authenticate(
            "HIDDEN",
            "HIDDEN",
            {
                userId: "Stock",
                auth: require("../../../../../index").hashGenerator("Stock")
            },
            {},
             (client) => {
                client.bigDB.loadOrCreate("StockItems", "Stock", function (obj) {
                    req.config.stockItems.map(item => {
                        items.push({
                            name: item.name,
                            img: item.img,
                            price: item.price,
                            stock: obj[item.img] ?? 5
                        })
                    })
                    req.render("/dynamic/pricing/index.liquid", { stockItems: items, Chests: req.config.chests});
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        );

        return req
    });

    done()
};

module.exports = index;
```

Comment: @jabaa I still can't get it working

Comment: Where are the first and second log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple improvements to do in your handler

- the plugin function is an async function and it has the done argument

> It is important to not mix callbacks and async/Promise, otherwise the hook chain will be executed twice.

https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#respond-to-a-request-from-a-hook
It is true for hooks but for plugins as well.

- the handler is async and the `req` is returned - fastify does not care about the REQUEST, it will wait `res`, the REPLY, so your route replies with an empty response..
- in case of errors, the reply should be fulfilled or it will starve
- `req.render` does not exist https://github.com/fastify/point-of-view so you have unhandled errors somewhere for sure

Here is a cleaned version of the code:

```js
const db = require('playerio-node')
const auth = require('../../../../../index').hashGenerator('Stock')

const index = async (fastify, options) => {
  fastify.get('/pricing', (req, reply) => {
    db.PlayerIO.authenticate(
      'HIDDEN',
      'HIDDEN',
      {
        userId: 'Stock',
        auth
      },
      {},
      (client) => {
        client.bigDB.loadOrCreate('StockItems', 'Stock', function (obj) {
          // ? what if loadOrCreate fails?
          const items = req.config.stockItems.map(item => {
            return {
              name: item.name,
              img: item.img,
              price: item.price,
              stock: obj[item.img] ?? 5
            }
          })

          reply.render('/dynamic/pricing/index.liquid', {
            stockItems: items,
            Chests: req.config.chests
          })
        })
      },
      (error) => {
        reply.send(error)
      }
    )
  })
}
```